# Macro returns #REF! in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know if this is the place to ask such a question, but since it was regarding some VBA scripting, I thought it might.

I have been writing this Macro function:

```
Function Mod10(tl As String) As Byte

    Dim c(13) As Integer
    Dim er As Integer

    c(13) = Mid(tl, 14, 1) * 2
    c(12) = Mid(tl, 13, 1)
    c(11) = Mid(tl, 12, 1) * 2
    c(10) = Mid(tl, 11, 1)
    c(9) = Mid(tl, 10, 1) * 2
    c(8) = Mid(tl, 9, 1)
    c(7) = Mid(tl, 8, 1) * 2
    c(6) = Mid(tl, 7, 1)
    c(5) = Mid(tl, 6, 1) * 2
    c(4) = Mid(tl, 5, 1)
    c(3) = Mid(tl, 4, 1) * 2
    c(2) = Mid(tl, 3, 1)
    c(1) = Mid(tl, 2, 1) * 2
    c(0) = Mid(tl, 1, 1)

    For i = 0 To 13
        If c(i) > 9 Then
            c(i) = CInt(Left(c(i), 1)) + CInt(Right(c(i), 1))
        End If
    Next

    er = 0
    For i = 0 To 13
        er = er + c(i)
    Next

    Mod10 = 10 - er Mod 10

End Function
```

But as you can see here in this picture:

[image]

it returns an error saying `#REF!`. i am writing this in the fx: `=Mod10(a1)`.

The script is found here: http://kronsell.net/fikkontrol.htm (a danish site)
It is used to calculate the final digit to a string. A bit like when calculating the EAN-13 code, just another kind of calculation.

If anybody with VBA or EXCEL knowledge could tell me what to do, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why, but it looks like `Mod10` is a reserved keyword.  I tried renaming the function to `Mod_10` and it worked.

[image]

You may need to declare some variables if you hold `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Try this and call it from a cell with `=MOD_10(A1)`

```
   Function MOD_10(tl As String) As Byte

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c(13) As Integer
    Dim er As Integer

    c(13) = Mid(tl, 14, 1) * 2
    c(12) = Mid(tl, 13, 1)
    c(11) = Mid(tl, 12, 1) * 2
    c(10) = Mid(tl, 11, 1)
    c(9) = Mid(tl, 10, 1) * 2
    c(8) = Mid(tl, 9, 1)
    c(7) = Mid(tl, 8, 1) * 2
    c(6) = Mid(tl, 7, 1)
    c(5) = Mid(tl, 6, 1) * 2
    c(4) = Mid(tl, 5, 1)
    c(3) = Mid(tl, 4, 1) * 2
    c(2) = Mid(tl, 3, 1)
    c(1) = Mid(tl, 2, 1) * 2
    c(0) = Mid(tl, 1, 1)

    For i = 0 To 13
        If c(i) > 9 Then
            c(i) = CInt(Left(c(i), 1)) + CInt(Right(c(i), 1))
        End If
    Next

    er = 0
    For i = 0 To 13
        er = er + c(i)
    Next

    MOD_10 = 10 - er Mod 10

End Function
```

Comment: `MOD10` is a valid cell address (excel 2007+), just like `A1`

Comment: It's quite strange that VBE doesn't highlight it as a reserved keyword. Instead the function is just being ignored and not executed. If you try to rename it to `Function Rem()` it highlights it right away as `Rem` (*comment*) is a reserved keyword but I can't see any connection between `MOD()` function and `MOD10` as a function name :O

Comment: You also need to change the `Mod10` reference in the last line of the function to `Mod_10`.  Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: yeah.. both the macro function and the fx

Comment: ahh... Yeah.. I forgot the last line as you said.. perfect.

Comment: @mehow, it's not a reserved word, but it is a correct cell reference in excel from 2007 on. You will have the same issue in the name manager - you can name a cell **ABC1** in excel 2003, but you can't in 2007, as **ABC1** is a valid cell